# Prove that a B-Tree of N keys has N+1 leaves

Tags: algorithms, induction, trees

Let B be a B-tree of order m, containing N items. Prove by induction that B has N+1 leaves.

I know that you should use induction on the depth of the tree, but how?

EDIT: The properties of a B-Tree of order m are:

- Every node has at most m children
- Every non-leaf node (except root) has at least ⌈m/2⌉ child nodes
- The root has at least two children if it is not a leaf node
- A non-leaf node with k children contains k − 1 keys
- All leaves appear in the same level

Comment: Im assuming $B-$tree is a binary tree. it can't contain N items and have N+1 leaves.. what are items? aren't they the nodes? i think the correct question is that if its depth is $N$ they it has $N+1 $leaves

Comment: A B-Tree of order m is a tree which satisfies the following properties:

-- Every node has at most m children.
-- Every non-leaf node (except root) has at least ⌈m/2⌉ child nodes.
-- The root has at least two children if it is not a leaf node.
-- A non-leaf node with k children contains k − 1 keys.
-- All leaves appear in the same level.

Comment: It doesn't sound right- what is the relation between m and the number of leaves you are trying to prove?

Comment: the order of the tree (m)  defines the maximum number of keys that are in each node